# Spring Boot DI in Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, dependency-injection, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I am using Spring Boot Dependency Injection with Swing. I have managed to inject my variables in my MainFrame with

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
    launcher.launch();

}

public class Launcher {
 public void launch() {
    String[] contextPaths = new String[] { "app-Context.xml" };
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            contextPaths);

  }
}
```

and defining the init() method of my Mainframe in the app-Context.xml. But if I create Panels in MainFrame.init(), the variables in these Panels are not injected. I am not experienced with Spring at all, thus I dont know if I am doing something wrong or just have to create my Panels differently. So what do I have to do?

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't provided us nearly enough information. _" the variables in these Panels are not injected"_, so what, are you getting some exceptions then? If so show them. You should also be showing your app-context.xml. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to run. That means we should be able to copy and paste your code, and run it. Your question is about components in which you fail to show us any of. When a problem is not obvious, and question is poorly worded, it helps to be able to test out some code, that replicates the problem. Please read the link carefully

Comment: Keep in mind, if these are custom panel classes, in which you try and autowire some spring container managed components, and the panels themselves are managed by the container, the autowire will fail. Personally I would avoid having the UI components managed by the container. There are other ways around it, but like I said, I would need to see more to get a better idea of what you're trying to do, and be able to offer an suggestions.